# Short-hand command for creating matrices

Tags: arrays

Is it possible to use `\newcommand` to create commands for matrices?

For instance, I want to have a new command called `\threedimmat` that takes 9 arguments and produces a corresponding 3x3  matrix so that I don't need to create an array and write so many `&` and `\\` every time.

Comment: you can do this (what did you try?) but I don't advise it, 9 is the maximum so you can do 3x3 but then would need a different syntax for 4x4 and it is much harder for anyone to read the source or get syntax help in your editor. `&` is one character and `}{` is two so why is `{a}{b}{c}`   simpler that `a&b&c` ?

Comment: I am not sure how to do it with the array. I tried to create new commands like this ```\newcommand{\pp}[2]{\frac{\partial #1}{\partial #2}}```to write partial derivatives easier. I guess it makes things easier if I can drop all those ```\left(\begin{array}``` stuff when creating matrices.

Comment: use amsmath `pmatrix` not `array` then you don't need left( or {cccc}

Comment: Thank you! I'll have a look at it.

Comment: but you could do exactly as you show `\newcommand\foo[9]{\begin{array}{ccc}#1&#2&#3\\#4&#5&#6\\#7&#8&#9\end{array}}`

Comment: Oh yes, it works now. I don't know why but I tried something like this before and it somehow failed. Thank you so much!